# Special name for the picture Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to put a name to a message that is embed to a picture from random 
 I want to assign the custom name to the image.
I tried it with the 'let' code.I just started Javascript.Please help... :)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const pic = [Jhin = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/562384674505228303/562981534332878869/607280.png',
        Kalista = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/562384674505228303/562981683268157455/654259.jpg'];
    const pics = Math.floor((Math.random() * pic.length));
    const test = new Discord.RichEmbed()


        .setTitle('<JHIN OR KALISTA>')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter('BKBOT')
        .setImage(pic[pics]);

    message.channel.send(test);
};
exports.conf = {
    enabled: true,
    guildOnly: false,
    aliases: [''],
    permLevel: 0,
};

exports.help = {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'Rastgele komik paylaşımlar atar.',
    usage: 'kp',
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do so by first setting an array of objects to represent each person. They'd have the properties `name` for their name, and `image` for the URL to the picture you'd want displayed. Then you could generate a random number to represent the index of the chosen value in the array. Your code would be something like...

```js
let people = [
{name: 'Jhin', image: 'url'},
{name: 'Kalista', image: 'url'}
];

let person = people[Math.floor(Math.random()*people.length)];

let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle(person.name)
.setColor('#ffffff')
.setFooter('BKBOT')
.setImage(person.image);
message.channel.send(embed);
```